# Firestore Web Interface does not allow to create array

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem with the Firestore web interface. I want to create an array of objects. These objects contain another array of objects.

The Problem is the Webinterface doesn't let me create this structure. It always says "This Field could not be saved".

When I create this structure inside my App and push it to the Firestore Database it works however I can't edit/add anything to my array.

This is how the it looks like in my Database:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), Firestore does not support arrays nested within arrays (which is your case). I suggest you to refactor your code to work with only one level of arrays or, even better, to only use objects, as they are more performant and supported.

Comment: Ah thanks, I didn't knew about this. Strange that it works when you push nested array programmatically. I will try to think of a way without arrays then...